# Connecting ColdFusion 8 to Oracle 11g with JDBC

Tags: coldfusion, oracle11g, coldfusion-8

I created a datasource from my ColdFusion 8 admin using JDBC/Oracle Thin Client. The datasource creation was successful.

When Oracle encryption is configured as "Requested" I can browse my ColdFusion app. and run many functionalities with no problem. But when the Oracle encryption is configured as "Required" the connection fails.

The way I tested and know that it was failed was when I log in to my web app. It won't log me in. But when the Oracle is switched back as "Requested" I can log in successfully and run my tasks.

I have ColdFusion 8 Enterprise version and the operating system is Unix.
From the network dept, I was told they have the correct JAR file in place but not sure what is the correct JAR file.

Currently my web apps are running with datasource created using Oracle Thin Clint but the Oracle encryption needs to be switched back to "Requested" otherwise my users are complaining that they can't log in.

Has anyone ever experienced this situation and found a solution?
What should I do so I can use Oracle encryption set to "Required"?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the ojdbc14.jar file in the ColdFusion8/wwwroot/WEB-INF/lib directory (this will work with 11g).

I would give Coldfusion a restart but it might not be unnecessary.

Navigate to your Coldfusion Administrator.

In the ColdFusion Administration under data sources. Add a new data source along with your credentials and choose Other from the Database driver options.

Then enter this: jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.11:1521:ORCL in the JDBC URL Textarea.

In the Driver Class textfield enter oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.

If you need a different jar (not sure you will) but if you do you can down load it from here.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html

Hope this is helpful or at least gets you further along.

Answer (score 0):

Frank, Thank you for the answer but the java version running on my CF server is JAVA1.6 and the ojdbc.jar that's installed in there is ojdbc6.jar
Should the version of ojdbc.jar and java be the same? If I am already in the right track with my ojdbs.jar and java files then I'm back to square one

In addition, my further test using Oracle encryption as "Requested", I can run my apps. just fine except when my CF made a call to a str. procedure, it did not return a result. So I got CF error.
From me googling this issue, I found a blog that says this is a problem on CF standard version when using Oracle Thin Client. My CF is Enterprise edition. 
I'm confused...is this related? how can I make this work?